# Difference between files of extension .asc, .asc.aux.xml, .aux and .rrd?

Tags: raster, lidar, esri-ascii-raster, terminology, rrd

I have received ASCII data from a client. These ASCII files have been created from LiDAR data.

For each tile there are 4 different file types:

- Filename.asc
- Filename.asc.aux.xml
- Filename.aux
- Filename.rrd

What is the purpose of these files (asc.aux.xml, aux, .rrd)?

Comment: Are these ASCII files point cloud data or derived raster data?

Answer (score 2):

These files are described in the ArcGIS Help:

- From [Reduced resolution dataset files](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/reduced-resolution-dataset-files.htm):

> A reduced resolution dataset (.rrd) file is one method of storing the
>   pyramid layers for a raster dataset.

- From [Auxiliary files](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/auxiliary-files.htm):

> An auxiliary file (.aux or .aux.xml) accompanies the raster in the
>   same location and stores any additional information that cannot be
>   stored in the raster file itself.